# MATCH within a BYROW LAMBDA in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet that's just a list of names. It's being used as a reference for a few places, one of which transposes the list to use the names as column headers in another sheet (offset by 1).

I can get the column letter for the corresponding name through a combination of `MATCH` and `ADDRESS`: `=ADDRESS(1, MATCH("some name", A1:A) + 1)` where `A1:A` is the list of names.

This is all well and good, however I'd like to essentially loop through the row of names, do some calculations based on the aforementioned sheet with these names as column headers, and then filter out to a specific result. My problem however is that `MATCH` (nor `XMATCH`) seem to work within `BYROW`. The base for what I'm doing would be:
`=BYROW(A1:A, LAMBDA(row, { INDEX(row, 1, 1), MATCH(INDEX(row, 1, 1), A1:A) + 1 }))`

Problem is, it throws an error, specifically: "Result was not expanded automatically, please insert more rows (13)."

Just using the `LAMBDA()` alone works correctly having used the following to test:
`=LAMBDA(row, { INDEX(row, 1, 1), MATCH(INDEX(row, 1, 1), A1:A) + 1 })(A1)`

Why would `MATCH`/`XMATCH` not work within `BYROW`? Is there a way around this?

Using just the `LAMBDA()` function, I know all my formulae will work, assuming I can get `BYROW()` to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `match()` function works fine in a lambda. Your formula errors out because it is producing more results than fit in the sheet. To make it work, weed out blank values, like this:

```
=byrow( 
  filter(A1:A, len(A1:A)), 
  lambda( 
    value, 
    { value, match(value, A1:A, 0) + 1 } 
  ) 
)
```

In the event the values in column `A1:A` are unique, a simpler way to do the same is to just use `filter()`:

```
=filter( { A1:A, row(A1:A) + 1 }, len(A1:A) )
```

Always specify the `0` with `match()`, unless your data is sorted (and even then it is usually a good idea.)

Comment: I had considered just using a filter but unfortunately that won't work in my case, or rather it will but I'd eventually need to wrap it in a `BYROW` eventually for some other stuff. Other than that, you have once again helped me and my mush brain out, so thanks a lot :)